# is there a way to see what code is executing when revoking a method?

Tags: php, ide

to learn a library/framework i think the best way would be to use a class method and then see what code is executing in live.

then you see the method chain (input and output of each) and can also read the comments.

is there a such feature in any IDE or external application for php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that so called Debugger?

You can install ZendDebugger or XDebug in your IDE and trace through the code.

Comment: but isn't it only visible when you got an error in your code. cause i want to use a method properly but wanna see all the methods the code calls, what was passed to the method and what the method returned, throughout the method chain.

Comment: @fayer with a debugger you can step through the code line by line and it will show you how your application state changes. Xdebug is free. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I use xdebug with netbeans. it's working great for me. I had a blog post about it. if you are interested, may have a read. http://blog.elinkmedia.net.au/2010/02/08/netbeans-debugger-with-zend-framework/